# Why $\mathbb QG\simeq \mathbb Q\oplus \mathbb Q \Delta G$ in representation decomposition?

Tags: number-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite group, $\mathbb Q G$ is the regular representation of $G$ over $\mathbb Q$, then it has a decomposition $\mathbb Q\oplus \mathbb Q \Delta G$ where $\mathbb Q$ represents the trivial representation and $\Delta G$ is the augmented ideal of $G$.(i.e. kernel of the map $\mathbb Z G\rightarrow \mathbb Z$ by $\sum z_gg\rightarrow \mathbb \sum z_g$.)

How to prove the above statement? I have some knowledge on representation theory over $\mathbb C$ but not much over $\mathbb Q$.
(If it's a well known fact, is there some good references?)

Comment: It seems that the augmentation map $A:\mathbb{Z}G\to \mathbb{Z}$ extends to $A':\mathbb{Q}G\to\mathbb{Q}$ via $A'(\frac{p}{q}g):=\frac{p}{q}$ and $\ker(A')=\mathbb{Q}\Delta G$. In order to obtain the direct product you only need to know that the resulting short exact sequence splits. Which is something I can't prove yet, hence the comment.

Comment: @freakish: I think the following does it: any short exact sequence of (left) modules over a semisimple ring splits, and $\mathbb{Q}[G]$ is semisimple by Maschke.

Comment: @AlexWertheim yeah, that works.

Comment: @AlexWertheim but theres simplier argument. The splitting is $p/q\mapsto p/q(\sum_{g\in G} g)$. Probably scaled by $|G|$.

Comment: @freakish: nice, yes! (Incidentally, to link the two points of view, I am pretty sure that your splitting is precisely the splitting *constructed* in the proof of Maschke!)

Comment: @CYC Did you really mean to change from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Q$ in the post?  I just wonder if it's a typo or really what you meant.

Comment: @rschwieb It's not typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*Note:* I will use "$G$-representation" and "$kG$-module" words interchangeably which outside of pure algebra might not be the same. But here it is fine.</sup>

More generally consider a finite group $G$ and a field $k$. Then we have a short exact sequence of $kG$-modules:

$$0\to \ker(A)\to kG\xrightarrow{A} k\to 0$$

where $A$ is the augmentation map $A\big(\sum \lambda g\big)=\sum\lambda$.

Now let $v:=\sum_{g\in G} g\in kG$ which makes sense since $G$ is finite. This special element has the property that $hv=v$ for any $h\in G$. This shows that for any $\lambda\in k$ the linear map

$$f_{\lambda}:k\to kG$$
$$f_{\lambda}(1)=\lambda v$$

is actually a $kG$-module homomorphism. Now if $|G|x=1$ has a solution in $k$ (i.e. when $char(k)$ does not divide $|G|$) then $f_x$ is a splitting map for the augmentation map $A$ since $A(v)=|G|1$. So by the splitting lemma $kG$ is the direct sum of representations $k\oplus \ker(A)$. Assuming $char(k)$ doesn't divide $|G|$. This argument can be further generalized into [Maschke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem).

Now all you have to do is calculate $\ker(A)$ in case $k=\mathbb{Q}$ which is $\mathbb{Q}\Delta G$. I leave that as an exercise.

*Side note:* I wonder if $k$ can be replaced with any unital ring having a solution to $|G|x=1$. It looks so. I don't see where the assumption about $k$ being a field (or even commutative) is relevant. Although this might not work for Maschke's theorem.

Comment: The modern statement of Maschke's theorem appears in Lam's *First course in noncommutative rings*: "Let $k$ be any ring and $G$ be any finite group. Then $R[G]$ is semisimple iff $R$ is semisimple and the order of $G$ is a unit in $k$."

Comment: @rschwieb interesting finding, thank you. Although in this particular case I don't think that even "semisimple" matters. It seems that this particular short exact sequence always splits when $|G|$ is a unit in $R$, right?

Comment: I was just directly addressing your line "although this might not work for Maschke's theorem."

Comment: I remember there is some link between projectivity of the augmentation ideal and its splitting (of course, splitting implies it is projective, but the other direction is more interesting.) . The link might in fact only hold for finite groups. But I do remember looking into projectivity of $\Delta G$ [not long ago](https://mathoverflow.net/q/297043/19965), and finding some interesting results in the literature. It is possible to have a projective augmentation ideal with an infinite group.

Comment: in the context above, $\Delta G$ projective *is* equivalent to it being a summand, since $\mathbb Q[G]$ is quasi-Frobenius.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\sum_g z_g g = (\sum_g z_g) 1 + \{\sum_{g} z_g g - [(\sum_g z_g) 1]\}$.

Comment: I see what you try here but this gives a decomposition only in terms of vector spaces. Unfortunately elements of the form $(\sum z)1$ (i.e. $\mathbb{Q}1$) do not form a $\mathbb{Q}G$-submodule.